# PFImageView Memory Problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, parse-platform, uicollectionview

I'm having a problem with a custom collection view of PFImages taking up way too much memory. In Parse, I've only got 7 objects, but the memory is reaching up to 1.1 gigabytes when loading the collection view. Also, the memory is not deallocating when leaving the view.

Here's my code

**Custom cell**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        [self setup];
        }
    return self;
} 
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)anotherDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:anotherDecoder];

    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setup {
    self.pictureImageView = [[PFImageView alloc]init];
    self.pictureImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.pictureView.frame.size.width, self.pictureView.frame.size.height);

    [self.contentView addSubview:pictureImageView];
}
```

**Collection View Code**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
PicturesCollectionViewCell *cell = (PicturesCollectionViewCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    tempObject =  [picturesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    PFFile *file = [tempObject objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
    cell.pictureImageView.file = file;

    cell.pictureImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"LOADING.png"];
    [cell.pictureImageView loadInBackground];

    cell.pictureImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

    cell.titleLabel.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"title"];

    NSLog(@"Image: %@, File: %@, at index: %li", cell.pictureImageView.image, cell.pictureImageView.file, indexPath.row);

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: PFImageView has open source code, I think they use NSCache there which will purge itself on memory warning.

Answer (score 0):

Parse is terrible with this situation... the code will trigger a purge when it gets a memory warning, this helps sometimes:

```
 - (void)removeCacheFiles {

      [PFQuery clearAllCachedResults];

      NSString *cacheDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
          NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
      NSString *nsurlDir =
          [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/YOUR_BUNDLE_ID", cacheDir];
      NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

      // grab all the files in the documents dir
      NSArray *allFiles = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:nsurlDir error:nil];

      // filter the array for only sqlite files
      NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.db'"];
      NSArray *dbFiles = [allFiles filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];

      // use fast enumeration to iterate the array and delete the files
      for (NSString *dbFile in dbFiles) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        [manager removeItemAtPath:[nsurlDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbFile]
                            error:&error];
        if (error != nil) {
          NSLog(@"Error:%@", [error description]);
        } else {
          NSLog(@"DB FILE Cleared: %@", dbFile);
        }
      }
    }
```